# Javascript await for response before returning result JS plugin

Tags: javascript

I've build a JS plugin that I'm loading into my project. I'm using Gulp 4 to compile everything, and I'm struggling with one of my methods. The method accepts a boolean value of `true` or `false`, and if the value of `true` is specified, then the function that the method calls runs an API request which updates my plugin's options.

However, in the project that listens for the response of the method, it doesn't account for the response of the API request.

**Plugin:**

```js
(function() {
  this.MyPlugin = function() {

    /*
    ** Settings
    **
    **    Default settings of the plugin that we can overwrite later
    */

    const INBOUND_CONFIG = {
      features: {
        settingOne: 'setting one',
        settingTwo: 'setting two'
      }
    }


    // Create options by extending defaults with the passed in arugments
    if (arguments[0] && typeof arguments[0] === "object") {
      this.options = extendDefaults(INBOUND_CONFIG, arguments[0]);
    }



    /*
    ** Compile Detailed Settings
    **
    **    Compile detailed settings
    */

    function compactFeatures (config) {
      const tlp_aff_id = buildTlpAffID(
        config.features.cpm_id,
        config.features.sub_id,
        config.brand
      )

      return {
        tlp_aff_id: tlp_aff_id
      }
    }



    /*
    ** Get inbound options
    **
    **    Get inbound options if we're not on the inbound page so that they're,
    **    accessible throughout the app
    */

    function getSettings (prefersDB = false) {
      purgeInboundConfig(false)

      let inbound

      if (localStorage.getItem('example--inbound')) {
        inbound = JSON.parse(encodeAndDecode(localStorage.getItem('example--inbound'), 'decode'))
      } else {
        inbound = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('example--inbound'))
      }

      // prefers db
      if (prefersDB) {
        fetchFromDB()
        return
      }

      let features = { ...compare(inbound, INBOUND_CONFIG.features), ...compactFeatures(INBOUND_CONFIG) }

      INBOUND_CONFIG.features = validateInboundSettings(features)
    }



    /*
    ** Comparison
    **
    **    We need to compare the inbound settings parsed against the default,
    **    settings that we have. If one from the inbound settings matches a,
    **    default one, we overwrite it and use the value from the inbound
    */

    function compare (inbound, defaults) {
      let settings = defaults

      if (!inbound) return settings

      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(inbound)) {

        for (var option in defaults) {
          if (defaults.hasOwnProperty(option)) {
            if (key == option) {
              settings[key] = convertToOriginalType(value)
              continue
            }
          }
        }

      }

      return settings
    }



    /*
    ** Find Affiliate from DB
    **
    **    Find an affiliate from the DB and fetch the appropriate data
    **
    */

    function fetchFromDB () {
      const query = JSON.parse(encodeAndDecode(localStorage.getItem('example--query'), 'decode'))

      // construct the data that we need
      const data = {
        affiliate: query.cpm_id ?? '',
        query: query ?? []
      }

      makeInboundHTTPRequest('POST', `https://example.com/api/affiliate/find`, 5000, JSON.stringify(data), function () {
        const res = JSON.parse(this.response.data.response)
        INBOUND_CONFIG.features = res.options ?? []

        // rerun to get settings
        getSettings()
      })

    }



    /*
    ** HTTP requests
    **
    **    This function will handle HTTP requests made by the plugin to and from,
    **    the processor.
    */

    function makeInboundHTTPRequest (
      type = 'GET',
      url = '',
      timeout = 30000,
      payload = null,
      callback
    ) {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()

      xhr.open(type, url, true)

      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')

      xhr.timeout = timeout
      xhr.ontimeout = () => {
        callback.apply({
          response: { error: true, message: `Timeout exceeded ${timeout}ms`, data: null }
        })
      }

      xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          if (xhr.response != null) {
            callback.apply({
              response: { error: false, message: 'Success', data: xhr }
            })
          } else {
            callback.apply({
              response: { error: false, message: 'No data', data: null }
            })
          }
        }
      }

      xhr.onerror = () => {
        callback.apply({
          response: { error: true, message: 'Generic error', data: null }
        })
      }

      if (type === 'POST') {
        xhr.send(payload)
        return
      }


      xhr.send()
    }



    /*
    ** Get Inbound Options
    **
    **    Get Inbound Config
    */

    MyPlugin.prototype.getSettings = function(prefersDB = false) {
      getSettings(prefersDB)
      return INBOUND_CONFIG.features
    }



    /*
    ** Extend Defaults
    **
    **    Utility method to extend defaults with user options
    */

    function extendDefaults(source, properties) {
      var property;
      for (property in properties) {
        if (properties.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
          source[property] = properties[property];
        }
      }
      return source;
    }

  }



  /*
  ** Plugin Loaded
  **
  **    Let the client know that the plugin is working!
  */

  window.postMessage('example--inbound-ready', '*')

}());
```

The above code is incomplete and doesn't contain every function, but purely contains the related one to my question which is:

```js
MyPlugin.prototype.getSettings = function(prefersDB = false) {
  getSettings(prefersDB)
  return INBOUND_CONFIG.features
}
```

Now, if I add a `setTimeout` to this method, then `INBOUND_CONFIG.features` has the correct returned response when the value of `true` is passed to the function, otherwise it doesn't

**Site**

```js
/*
** Define our plugins
**
**    Define our plugins that we want to enable
*/

var inbound

const plugins = {
  inbound: {
    isEnabled: false
  }
}



/*
** Enable Plugins
**
**    Listen for plugins, if they're included then let's enable them
*/

const eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? 'addEventListener' : 'attachEvent'
const eventer = window[eventMethod]
const messageEvent = eventMethod == 'attachEvent' ? 'onmessage' : 'message'

// Listen to message from child window
eventer(messageEvent, function(e) { // eslint-disable-line prefer-arrow-callback
  const str = e.data.toString()


  if (str == 'myplugin--inbound-ready') {

    // Enable the plugin
    plugins.inbound.isEnabled = true

    // Load Inbound Plugin
    if (plugins.inbound.isEnabled) {
      mypluginInbound = new MyPlugin()
      inbound = mypluginInbound.getSettings(true) <-- this doesn't contain updated api settings
    } else {
      inbound = ''
    }

  }

}, false)
```

How can I make my `getSettings` method wait for a response, do I add a set timeout to it, or a promise? I can't use async/await in this project for bigger reasons.

Comment: What about Promises (Even though async / await is syntactic sugar around Promises)?

Comment: They'd have to communicate between the two files, not sure how that would work, i.e: the promise code inside of the plugin and then the resolve part in the main project

Comment: No problem. `getSettings` can return a Promise instead of an object. The caller of it can run `getSettings(true).then(settings => doSomething)`

Comment: Example? Because `MyPlugin.prototype.getSettings` runs `getSettings` which in turn makes the request, so how can it know about the updated data to return?

Comment: Something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/7qh6L05n/5/ (go to javascript)